# How do I run a function with a table update trigger?

Tags: ms-access, triggers

I'm new in this forum and this is my first question.

I've made a database in access for process control and I want to have the this database separated in local applications, linked with the tables, on the server.

Once this database is a process controller, it has a control pannel, designed in a form, with buttons that indicate different states during the process. This control pannel is opened in several computers and must be updated every time the tables are updated. How do I spread the trigger for all the database users? I've tried already, but only the active app, this means, the app who changed the table, is modified.

Pleasem, help! I don't know whatelse to do.

Comment: You should really at least acknoledge the effort if someone gives you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The backend database (access) you use is simply a data storage. It cannot run VBA itself or raise events. So you have to rely on your frontends to detect data-changes. And strangely access detecs no datachanges in open forms that do not originate from the respective client.
So you will have to check for changes yourself. The best bet would probably be with a timer and a routine that checks either for datachanges in a remote table or for some other trigger (like file change time etc..)
If you have any kind of server you could also create a small service where each of your access-instances can register. Then you could create triggers (afterChange or whatever you need) in your frontends that call that service, which then calls teh respective routines in each of the registered instances. This would be preferable, if you have many frontend running or if network load is of concern.